# How reliable is the data from College Scorecard?

Tags: collegescorecard

I'm looking to use the College Scorecard API for an app. However, I had a few questions about it.

How do they collect the data?
How often do they refresh it?
How is it secured?
How reliable is it? / Do they have outages?
What security mechanism do they use?